# Finding button ids created in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a grid of buttons in the form of images. It is currently a 5x5 grid. I was to store the ids of the buttons so I can track which ones the user has selected so that I can either highlight their background to show they are selected, or keep them active until the user clicks them again.

Printing out the buttonID list gives me `<class 'tkinter.Button'>`

````
displayedList = images
buttonID = []
#create the grid here using rows and columns 
nrows = 5
ncols = 5
displayedList = images

for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, len(displayedList)- 1)
        tk.Button(padx=50, pady=50, image=displayedList[randomNumber]).grid(row = r, column=c) 
        buttonID.append(Button)

    displayedList.remove(displayedList[randomNumber])
displayedList = images ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the button object of the new button.

Try this:

```
 btn = tk.Button(padx=50, pady=50, image=displayedList[randomNumber])
 btn.grid(row = r, column=c) 
 buttonID.append(btn)
```

You should store the button objects instead of just the IDs so it is easier to reference them later.

Comment: This code won't work. `buttonID` will end up being `[None, None, None, None, None]`

Comment: So it does. But it still helped me a little, but I have not yet figured this issue out.

Comment: I missed the `grid` call. Answer updated to get the correct object.